# Problema com React Native

Tags: react-native

Eu fiz toda a instalação do React Native normalmente, Instalei o Genymotion para emular a aplicação, dei o `react-native run-android` e o app instalou no emulador normalmente, porém quando dou `react-native start` ele fica monstrando **Loading dependency graph...** infinitamente, o App não carrega porra nenhuma e minha RAM vai pro krl. Eu tô a 3 dias procurando solução e nd, alguém me ajuda, plmds

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

tenta remover os pacotes `rm -rf node_modules/` e reinstala-los novamente `npm start` e depois roda com `react-native run-android`

der um downgrade no react-native `react-native init --version 0.59.9 NOMEDOPROJETO`

Comment: fiz e nd deu certo, meus 8gb de ram somem como se fossem nd. Vou tentar recriar o projeto

Comment: O que aparece na tela do emulador? você tem posta pelo menos uma imagem do que aparece na tela do aplicativo

Comment: Dei Downgrade no React native e funcionou, mas vlw mesmo assim